# Xdebug - Visual Studio Code - Step into / Step over - Nothing happens

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, windows-10, xdebug

I'm having an issue with Visual Studio Code and Xdebug.

**My System:**

I'm using a `Windows 10` system with `IIS` webserver and `PHP` version 7.4.
I've downloaded and installed `Xdebug` with the last version (2.9.0) successfully (see the excerpt from the `php.ini` below).
Visual Studio Code is configured for using Xdebug (see `launch.json` file below).

**My issue is:**

When I set a breakpoint, it stops at this breakpoint. So far so good. But if I press then "Step into" (F11) or "Step over" (F10) buttons, nothing is happening at all. The initial breakpoint is still highlighted - it stays at the breakpoint.

[image]

Maybe something is configured wrong, but actually I can't figure out what it is.

See here the configuration files:

**php.ini:**

```
[XDEBUG]
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
xdebug.remote_log ="C:\temp\xdebug.log"

[PHP_XDEBUG-2.9.0-7.4-VC15-NTS]
zend_extension = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.4\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.0-7.4-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll"
```

**launch.json of Visual Studio Code:**

```
{
    // Verwendet IntelliSense zum Ermitteln möglicher Attribute.
    // Zeigen Sie auf vorhandene Attribute, um die zugehörigen Beschreibungen anzuzeigen.
    // Weitere Informationen finden Sie unter https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "ignore": [
                "**/vendor/**/*.php"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Make a log by setting in php.ini: `xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.org`, and then `tail -f /tmp/xdebug.org` it to see what happens on the wire.

Comment: Many thanks. That helped to figure out the problem. The issue was, that there were breakpoints on deleted files.

Comment: That shouldn't cause a problem though. What happened in your log? (Or can you share it, while pointing out where it went wrong through https://bugs.xdebug.org )

Comment: I need to check, if I still have the log file. Actually I did 2 things: Cleared the breakpoints (even of deleted files) and cleared all watched variables. Nothing more - then it worked.

Comment: @Derick I was able to reproduce this behaviour, but the log file from xdebug is too long to post it in this post. It is always, when I have variables in the "Watch"-section of Visual Studio. If I clear this section it works fine.

Comment: File a bug report with the log attached at https://bugs.xdebug.org then, so we can have a check whether it's not a bug in Xdebug.

Comment: @Derick I've created a bug report there. ID 0001735

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This turned out to be a [bug](https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1735) in Xdebug, which would happen when the following points are all true:

- An [error handler](https://php.net/set_error_handler) converted a warning/notice into an Exception
- An exception breakpoint was set on this specific Exception, or a wild card exception breakpoint was set
- The DBGp [`eval command`](https://xdebug.org/docs/dbgp#eval), which IDEs often use to implement watches, created a warning or notice, in this case, due to an undefined variable.

The cause was that although the `eval` command turns of breakpoints with a *breakpoints_allowed* flag until it has been run, the breakpoint handler for *exceptions* did not check whether this *breakpoints_allowed* flag was actually set.

The [fix](https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/commit/9bd6c301395bf31e1fec5d451897bf80f1aca69f#diff-83ceffe782410fc67e5fc23aea0659edR292) is to check for the *breakpoints_allowed* flag in the handler for exception breakpoints, and will be part of the upcoming Xdebug 2.9.2 release. If you don't want to wait, download Xdebug from [Github](https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug) and make sure to use the `xdebug_2_9` branch (unless you want to go really experimental).